# Class serialization in XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

```
[XmlRoot("Class1")]
class Class1
{
[(XmlElement("Product")]
public string Product{get;set;}
[(XmlElement("Price")]
public string Price{get;set;}
}
```

This is my class. In this the price contains the '£' symbol. after serializing it to XML I get the '?' instead of '£'.

what I need to do to get the '£' in XML? OR How can I pass the data in price as CDATA?

Comment: Show us the serialization code.

Comment: actually I do have a library developed by other team. we use that library only and we get the serialized XML. I'm getting everything fine except that '£' sign.

Comment: Sounds like something to do with encoding - is the output being written in UTF8?

Comment: Yes the output is written in UTF8 ecoding

Comment: XmlSerializerNamespaces Xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            Xsn.Add("", "");
            XmlSerializer Submit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringWriter StringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter Writer = XmlWriter.Create(StringWriter);
            Submit.Serialize(Writer, obj, Xsn);
            StringWriter.ToString(); // Your xml  This is the serialization code. In this Obj is the object to serialize

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be to do with how the XML is written to the file.

I've written a program that uses the information that you've given me so far, and it when I print the XML string out, it is correct.

I conclude that the error is happening either when the data is written to the XML file, or when it is read back in from the XML file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        void Run()
        {
            Class1 test = new Class1();
            test.Product = "Product";
            test.Price = "£100";

            Test(test);
        }

        void Test<T>(T obj)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces Xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            Xsn.Add("", ""); 
            XmlSerializer submit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter); 
            submit.Serialize(writer, obj, Xsn); 
            var xml = stringWriter.ToString(); // Your xml This is the serialization code. In this Obj is the object to serialize

            Console.WriteLine(xml);  // £ sign is fine in this output.
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Class1")]
    public class Class1
    {
        [XmlElement("Product")]
        public string Product
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Price")]
        public string Price
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you are on the right track with your response. While the XML may be serialized as UTF-8, is the file that is saved encoded as UTF-8? Also, if there's no BOM, Windows tries to "guess" the encoding, and sometimes it gets it wrong. This is very apparent when using UTF-8 characters in a file that Windows thinks is ANSI or CP-1252--invalid characters are displayed as `?` because there's no corresponding character. Just some thoughts to help everyone along.